# MySQL count listing between certain price range

Tags: mysql, count, range, between

From another post on the site, I took the following type of query.  They were using sum, I am looking for a count of listings.

```
SELECT
COUNT(IF(sold_price < 20,1,0)) as 'Under 20',
COUNT(IF(sold_price BETWEEN 20 and 50,1,0)) as '20 - 50',
COUNT(IF(sold_price BETWEEN 50 and 100,1,0)) as '50 - 100',
COUNT(IF(sold_price BETWEEN 100 and 250,1,0)) as '100 - 250',
COUNT(IF(sold_price BETWEEN 250 and 500,1,0)) as '250 - 500',
COUNT(IF(sold_price BETWEEN 500 and 1000,1,0)) as '500 - 1000',
COUNT(IF(sold_price BETWEEN 1000 and 2000,1,0)) as '1000 - 2000',
COUNT(IF(sold_price > 2000,1,0)) as 'Over 2000'
FROM listings
where current_batch = 'Y'
```

All my results are coming back as the same number

```
Under 20    20 - 50 50 - 100    100 - 250   250 - 500   500 - 1000  1000 - 2000 Over 2000
94665   94665   94665   94665   94665   94665   94665   94665
```

Does anyone have any suggestion on show to do this or if this can be done with count?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL documentation says the following(http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count):

`COUNT(expr)
Returns a count of the number of non-NULL values of expr in the rows retrieved by a SELECT statement`

So replace:

```
IF(sold_price BETWEEN 20 and 50,1,0)
```

by

```
IF(sold_price BETWEEN 20 and 50,1,NULL)
```

Comment: Fantastic.  I love it when its something simple like that.  Thank you VERY much for you help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Use SUM instead of COUNT in your query like:

```
SELECT
SUM(CASE WHEN our_price <= 10000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS p10000,
SUM(CASE WHEN our_price >= 10001 AND our_price <= 25000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS p25000,
SUM(CASE WHEN our_price >= 25001 AND our_price <= 50000  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS p50000,
SUM(CASE WHEN our_price >= 50001 AND our_price <= 75000  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS p75000,
SUM(CASE WHEN our_price >= 75001 AND our_price <= 100000  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS p100000,
SUM(CASE WHEN our_price >= 100001 AND our_price <= 150000  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS p150000,
SUM(CASE WHEN our_price >= 151000 AND our_price <= 200000  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS p200000,
SUM(CASE WHEN our_price > 200000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS p200001
FROM products;
```